# Dynamically create a delegate from a Type[]

Tags: c#, delegates

Is it possible to create a delegate from a Type[], for example:

```
Delegate CreateDelegate(params Type[] types)
{
    Type delegateType = Expression.GetDelegateType(types);
    return Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, /*some method info*/);
}
```

This is to pass into a generic method to cast to this delegate, for example:

```
void Call<TDelegate>(string func, out object? returnValue, TDelegate typeDelegate, params object?[]? args) where TDelegate : Delegate
{
    nint lib = LoadLibrary("library.dll");
    
    nint address = GetProcAddress(lib, "Add");

    TDelegate function = (TDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(address, typeof(TDelegate));
    returnValue = function(args);
    FreeLibrary(lib);
}
```

So this example could be used like:

```
object? ret;
Call("Add", out ret, CreateDelegate(typeof(int), typeof(int), typeof(int)), 32, 67);
Console.WriteLine(ret);
```

with the function add in library.dll:
header:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int Add(int a, int b);
```

source:

```
int Add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

And the output should be:

> 99

The purpose of `typeDelegate` is so the type of `TDelegate` is inferred. The method info needed in this `CreateDelegate` method is not important in this case. Is this possible or is there any way to pass the `delegateType` created into a generic?

Comment: It's certainly possible to create a delegate dynamically. But calling a PInvoke function is usually far more complex than just a basic delegate, usually requiring custom attributes (in your case at the very least `UnmanagedFunctionPointer` with `CallingConvention`) and therefore probably a dynamic function

Comment: What is the use case? Have you taken a look at Nihlus's ADL library? https://github.com/Nihlus/AdvancedDLSupport